# Finding all posts I have written in a Facebook fanpage

Tags: facebook-pages

Is there a way to find all posts/comments I made in a given Facebook fanpage?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of is to use the [ArchiveFacebook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/archivefacebook/) Firefox add-on to download your Facebook data (or at least some parts of it) and search it for messages posted to the fanpage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if those posts are part of the downloadable archive that you can download from Facebook. If it is, which I think it is, then the challenge is that the archive includes all your posts, so you will have to parse the download and extract the posts you're looking for.